# Iterate over parts of data in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration

Data:
[Data visualed in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrJbK.png)

1. I have dataset as seen above.
2. Can i use python to create dataframes: first red, do some calculations, save results. Create the blue and do calculations, save some data and green and so on?
3. HELP! How!?

Answer (score 1):

You can start from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to use `pandas` and load up the data from the excel file in a dataframe `df`, then do something like

```
for window in df.rolling(window=2):
    # computation on the sliding window...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. what should be the result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about the calculation you need to perform.
But what you are looking for is a rolling window

```
df_result = df.rolling(window=size_of_window).apply(func_to_apply)
```